# Angular push objects to array return not function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, websocket

I'm trying to push returned data from `socket-io` into my messages array but it says:

> ERROR TypeError: this.messages.push is not a function

## Code

```
messages: any[] = [];

constructor(...){...}

ngOnInit() {
 this.socket.fromEvent('message').subscribe((message: any) => {
   console.log('from socket', message.msg.message); // sample data provided in down
   this.messages.push(message.msg.message);
 });
}
```

`sample data`

```
from socket 
    {id: 51, group_id: 1, user_id: 1, note: "wrwgwwg", deleted_at: null, …}
        created_at: "2020-05-18T08:19:59.000000Z"
        deleted_at: null
        group_id: 1
        id: 51
        note: "wrwgwwg"
        updated_at: "2020-05-18T08:19:59.000000Z"
        user: {id: 1, name: "Sam", username: "admin", phone: "081200000001", photo: null, …}
        user_id: 1
        __proto__: Object
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

my full component code as requested.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
import { MenuController, LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AlertService } from 'src/app/Services/alert.service';
import { SendChatService } from 'src/app/Services/send-chat.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { GroupsService } from 'src/app/Services/groups.service';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/Services/auth.service';
import { User } from 'src/app/Services/user.service';
const { Toast } = Plugins;

// socket.io
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.page.scss'],
})
export class ChatPage implements OnInit {

  newSegment: string;
  public chat: FormGroup;
  messages: any[] = [];
  loading: any;
  public user: User;

  constructor(
    private sendChatService: SendChatService,
    private groupsService: GroupsService,
    private menu: MenuController,
    private alertService: AlertService,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public loadingController: LoadingController,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private socket: Socket,
  ) {
    this.menu.enable(true);
    const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.chat = this.formBuilder.group({
      newMessage: ['', Validators.required],
      group_id: id
    });
  }

  async ionViewDidEnter() {
    (await this.authService.user()).subscribe(
      user => {
        this.user = user;
      }
    );
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.socket.disconnect();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    Toast.show({
      text: 'Selamat Datang Ke grup chat.'
    });
    this.getData();

    // socket.io
    this.socket.connect();

    // get back stored data form "sendMessage" and add it to the list
    this.socket.fromEvent('message').subscribe((message: any) => {
      console.log('from socket', message.msg.message);
      this.messages.push(message.msg.message);
    });
    // end of socket.io
  }

  async getData() {
    this.loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Please wait...',
      spinner: 'crescent',
      duration: 2000
    });

    await this.loading.present();

    const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.groupsService.getGroupsDetails(id).subscribe(res => {
      this.messages = res.data;
      this.hideLoading();
    });
  }

  private hideLoading() {
    this.loading.dismiss();
  }

  doRefresh(event) {
    console.log('Begin async operation');
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      event.target.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.newSegment = 'chats';
  }

  sendMessage() {
    const chatt = this.chat.value;
    this.sendChatService.messagesend(chatt.newMessage, chatt.group_id).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.alertService.presentToast(data.message);
        console.log(data);
        // this.messages.push(data);
        // chatt.newMessage.reset();
        // socket.io (send returned data to socket server - get it back in "ngOnInit")
        this.socket.emit('send-message', { message: data.data });
      },
      error => {
        this.alertService.presentToast(error.statusText);
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        //
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks good. Can you show us the code of the complete component?

Comment: @mafortis i have to agree with Marc. I've also tested your code exactly like this and i get no errors.

Comment: @Mikefox2k ok then i share it all.

Comment: `this.messages = res.data` - could you please say what is `res.data`?

Comment: is old messages from database (when user enter chat the old messages shows)

Comment: Is it an array?

Comment: Have you checked if it's really not empty? (`res.data`)

Comment: @MichaelD not it's object as well (group detail + array inside which contains messages).

Comment: @Mikefox2k no it's not empty i have it open here.

Comment: Try to include `if(res?.data && res?.data.length > 1)` before assigning it to `messages`.

Comment: @MichaelD broke my page

Comment: @MichaelD here is what i get based on `res.data` https://ibb.co/CtGk8K7

Comment: It looks like you need to assign `res.data.notes`. `res.data` is an object. And the `if` condition would be `if(res?.data?.notes && res?.data?.notes.length > 1)`.

Comment: @MichaelD that i do in html not in component, i pass my data to `messages` then in my view (html) i get my group name etc. also i can loop my messages.

Comment: @MichaelD here is sample for you of my current data https://ibb.co/rymwcHr

Comment: Could you write the whole message?

Comment: @StepUp already solved bro, i also published the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Solved

my messages had `notes` array inside ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61865373/angular-push-objects-to-array-return-not-function#comment109423308_61865373)) all I needed to do was to point new message inside that notes array instead of messages itself.

So the final code is:

```
this.messages.notes.push(message.msg.message);
```

instead of

```
this.messages.push(message.msg.message);
```

Comment: One tip: rework your naming, it get's confusing really fast.

Answer (score 0):

Messages is in the beginning an array, but then I see this line:

```
this.messages = res.data;
```

Make sure, that res.data is really an array. Or do this:

```
this.messages = [...res.data];
```

or:

```
this.messages.push(res.data);
```

or fix the backend: this.socket.fromEvent('message')...

Comment: now you see why i said is not good idea to share full code? :) you wen't to irrelative codes as i predicted.

Comment: One tip from my side:  never use any.

Comment: in which part? `messages: any[] = [];` or `.subscribe((message: any)`?